How to set default value to Html with Chrome extension called "textarea to code editor"
Question: Is there some way to set Html as the default value for the Google Chrome extension named textarea to code editor?
The default value is plain text or Normal textarea (see top picture).
If I click the Submit button the textarea defaults back to plain text. I have to right click and then select the Html value from the dropdown menu (see bottom picture).
Thank you in advance.


